# How to determine if a file has been modified recently with bash on mac

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

**Background:**

I'm trying to add something to my bash profile to see if a backup is outdated and then make a quick backup if not.

**The Question**

Basically I'm trying to see if a file is older than an arbitrary date. I can find the most recently updated file with

```
lastbackup=$(ls -t file | head -1)
```

And I can get last modified date with

```
stat -f "%Sm" $lastbackup
```

But I can't figure out how to compare that time with bash functions, or how to make a timestamp, etc.

All the other answers I found seem to use the non mac versions of `stat` with differently supported flags. Looking for any clues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The find command will do what you're looking for quite nicely. Say you want to ensure you have a backup that is no older than 1 day every day (that you login), here is a test setup with two files, the find syntax, and the output you will see.

```
# Create a backup directory and cd to it
mkdir backups; cd backups

# Create file, oldfile and set oldfile last mod time to 2 days ago
touch file
touch -a -m -t 201801301147 oldfile

# Find files in this folder with modified time within 1 day ago;
# will only list file
find . -type f -mtime -1

# If you get no returned files from find, you know you need to run
# a backup.  You could do this (replace run-backup with your backup command):
lastbackup=$(find . -type f -mtime -1)
if [ -z "$lastbackup" ]; then
  run-backup
fi
```

If you view the manpage for find, look at the -atime switch for details on other units you can use (e.g. hours, minutes).

Answer (score 3):

You can use seconds since the epoch for the actual date and the last file change and then decide if a backup is needed based on the difference of seconds.

Something like this: (edit: changed stat parameters to match OS X options)

```
# today in seconds since the epoch
today=$(date +%s)
# last file change in seconds since the epoch
lastchange=$(stat -f '%m' thefile)
# number of seconds between today and the last change
timedelta=$((today - lastchange))
# decide to do a backup if the timedelta is greater than
# an arbitrary number of second
# ie. 7 days (7d * 24h * 60m * 60s = 604800 seconds)
if [ $timedelta -gt 604800 ]; then
   do_backup
elif
```

Comment: Yeah, but the mac version of `stat` doesn't have the -c option

Comment: I don't have an OS X in hand but the on-line man page of stat says you have the options -r and -f format. Can't you combine them to get the last change date in seconds since the epoch?

Comment: What is the output of `stat -r -f '%m' $lastbackup`? If I got the man page right, it will give you the last change in seconds since the epoch.

Comment: You can't use `-r` and `-f` together, but with out the `-r` this seems to work great. I'm going to go with the other answer since it seems to work a bit better with my use case, but if I could accept two I would.

Comment: No worries. We aim for pleasure. :-)